# Accessing Properties of an xml file in Word 2007

Tags: xml, xslt, ms-office, word-2007, wordml

I am writing style sheet for MS Word 2007 and I want to add a template using < xsl : template > element which accesses Properties of Word 2007 document. (Template, TotalTime, etc.) Can someone provide me with the code to start this?

Comment: You'll find 3 or 4 properties parts if you unzip a docx.  You'll find them easier to access via XSL if you save as "Flat OPC XML" (in Word, save as XML file).  Or are you trying to apply a transform from within Word?

Comment: @JasonPlutext I am writing a stylesheet for a Word 2007 xml file. Yes I unzipped the doc. I want to write a template using <xsl : template > tag to access the elements which are there in app.xml file. Once the stylesheet is applied to my xml file, I want to hide those properties in the resulting xml file. Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the stylesheet level, declare the namespaces prefixes you wish to use for namespaces in the Word 2007 Flat OPC XML:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
    xmlns:ep="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties"
    xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage"
    xmlns:vt="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/docPropsVTypes">
```

To remove the <Template> extended property (from what would be app.xml in a zipped up docx):

```
<xsl:template match="ep:Template" />
```